# In the Cities Skylines Asset Editor, how do I get a park to appear in the plaza tab?

Tags: cities-skylines

In Cities Skylines Asset Editor, I've managed to create a park, but I can't see any way of placing it into one of the tabbed categories that further breakdown the park tab.  Is there any way to do this?

Specifically, I'd like to create some plazas for my city that could go into the plaza tab.

Comment: This is something that much of the community wants, but there's no in-game way to do it. You could consider using a mod ([1](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=458396767), [2](http://community.simtropolis.com/forums/topic/67699-tutorial-how-to-change-an-assets-category-tab-while-still-retaining-service-info-of-another-category/))